# Can not find functions for text editing

Tags: api, class, text, google-apps-script, libraries

I am relatively new to the Google doc/sheets environment (I downloaded the suite about one week ago).

I have used the script editor and have had excellent results with spreadsheet functions, but when I attempt to perform functions from the `Text` Class such as `FIND, REPLACE, LEFT` I generate a `REFERENCEERROR`.

The autocomplete does not have these functions as I type. When I go to the spreadsheet I can use these functions in a cell and they work fine with the expected results.

It appears that part of the basic Google Service API is not available/loaded, however, I cannot find the API with Text Class in online help.

Can you please tell me which API I am missing and how to load it into the script editor? I understand how to load API calls into the script editor but I cannot find this specific API.

Comment: The text reference can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text)

Comment: Thank you. I have read the class description and I am familiar with it's function. My question is that it does not appear to be loaded in my editor and I would like to know specifically how to do that.Thank you once again.

Comment: Where are you writing your script, is it a document or a spreadsheet?

Comment: In spreadsheet editor.

Comment: Are you pulling the text from a Doc? Because the text element is only available in documents, not spreadsheets.

Comment: So there is no way to pull text class from API inSPREADSHEET editor?

Comment: You have to be working with a document then you can get it the same way you would get spreadsheet data even from a script within a spreadsheet. You cannot however use the text methods on a Spreadsheet.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. How would you parse text from spreadsheet cells with editor in spread sheet?

Comment: If you just want to use things like find and replace you want to use Javascripts default [regexp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) and [string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) methods

Comment: Thank you that is what I was looking for.